# Laravel 7 to an external API Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-7

i have problem with HTTP API post request using laravel 7
i tried with with postman is work fine

this my code :

```
       $response = Http::withOptions([
                    'debug' => true,
                ])->asForm()->withToken('mybearertoken')->post('theurl',[
                    'tracking' => $getcolisdetails->ref_order,
                    'state_id' => $newStatus ,
                    'content'  => $content
                                ]);
                                $response->json() ;
```

the response that i get :

```
"Argument 1 passed to Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given
```

Note : i use laravel 7 , PHP 7.4 , guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3

Answer (score 0):

the solution that i found using guzzle :

```
try {
    $response = (new Client([
      'debug' => true,
    ]))->post('theurl', [
      'headers' => [
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer mybearertoken',
      ],
      'json' => [
          'tracking' => $getcolisdetails->ref_order,
          'state_id' => $newStatus,
          'content'  => $content
      ],
    ]);
    $data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
  } catch (ClientException $exception) {
    dd($exception->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
  }
```